# Jquery animating image, position, width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one situation with animating "img", when i put my var complete inside click function it wont animate but when i make it outside function it's working.Does it have something with global and local scope? thank you

```
var complete = true;


$("img").click(function() {

    if (complete) {

        $(this).animate({
            left: "50%",
            top: "400px",
            width: "300px",
            height: "300px"

        }, 700);

    } else {

        $(this).animate({
            left: "8px",
            top: "10px",
            width: "150px",
            height: "150px"
        }, 700);
    }

    complete = !complete;
});
```

Comment: Yes, it's something related with global and local scope, If you variable declare ins side the click event function, means that variable scope inside the function - local scope within function, But when you declare outside the function, means you declare variable as globally - global scope, and you can use that variable where ever you want in side the page.

Comment: take a look to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) or [this doc](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/480/scope#t=201706211704131525277)

Answer (score 1):

If you put

```
var complete = true;
```

inside the callback for the `click` handler, it will be defined as `true` every time the function is invoked, which essentially redefines the function as

```
$("img").click(function() {

  if (true) {

    $(this).animate({

      left: "50%",
      top: "400px",
      width: "300px",
      height: "300px"

    }, 700);

  } else {

    $(this).animate({

      left: "8px",
      top: "10px",
      width: "150px",
      height: "150px"

    }, 700);

  }

});
```

And by simplifying further:

```
$("img").click(function() {

  $(this).animate({

    left: "50%",
    top: "400px",
    width: "300px",
    height: "300px"

  }, 700);

});
```

By defining `complete` outside of the function, the variable's value persists beyond a single call of the function, allowing the global state to be toggled by each call.